# Prove n is always a multiple of 4 for this sum to be 0.

Tags: number-theory, contest-math

Each of the numbers $x_1,x_2,x_3,...,x_n$ equals 1 or -1, and
$$x_1x_2x_3x_4 + x_2x_3x_4x_5 + ... + x_nx_1x_2x_3 = 0.$$
Prove that n is divisible by 4.

I attempted to solve this problem first by letting $x_1x_2x_3...x_n$ = $c$ where $c=-1$ or $c=1$ and rewriting but it didn't provide much use. It's pretty clear that n must be even, so from there we must prove that if n is even with only 1 factor of 2 this fails. Another idea I had was that I noticed we can write the term i+1 in terms of term i, by multiplying by $x_{i+5}/{xi}$. In the case of n=6 this provides some nice cancellations, but overall, nothing that I think helps me solve the problem. Any insights would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There are $n$ terms with $4$ variable each, and each variable occurs $4$ times in the sum.  Since the sum is $0$, there must be the same number of terms each to $1$ and $-1$, so that $n$ is even, say $n=2m$.  There are $m$ terms with an odd number of variables equal to $-1$ and $m$ terms with an even number of variables equal to $-1$.  Thus, if $m$ is odd, the total number of negative variables, counting each occurrence of each variable separately, is odd.  This is impossible, since the total number of negative occurrences is $4$ times the number of negative variables.  Then $m$ is even, and $m$ is divisible by $4$.

Answer (score -1):

Hint:  prove that changing the sign of one variable always changes the sign of the sum by a multiple of $4$.  You can do that just by looking at the possible values of the three variables before and after.  Then if all the variables are $1$ the sum is $n$.  You need this to be a multiple of $4$ to have a hope to get to $0$

Comment: Sorry if this is a stupid question, but what do you by "changes the sign of the sum by a multiple of 4"?

Comment: If you have one set of values for the $x$s and change the sign of one of them, the new sum minus the old sum is a multiple of $4$.  So if $n=10$ and you start with all the $x$s equal to $1$ the sum is $10$.  If you change one of them to $-1$ the sum becomes $2$, which is a difference of $8$.  $8$ is a multiple of $4$.  If you change the one after the one you changed first, the sum becomes $6$, a difference of $4$.